# Grouping multiple socket.io responses

Tags: javascript, sockets, callback, socket.io, promise

I have an application that needs to establish multiple websocket connections to *different* servers that output the same data structures. I am using Socket.IO to do this which is great, but presents some challenges for client-side management. Since the data structures returned are the same, I want to share callback handlers for any emit responses and group the results.

Here's a toy example I'd like to get working:

```js
function logger() {
    console.log("LOGGED");
}

var handles = {};
handles[0] = io('http://HOST-A:5000');
handles[1] = io('http://HOST-B:5000');
for (var key in handles) {
    var handle = handles[key];
    var states = ['connect', 'event', 'disconnect'];
    for (var j=0; j < states.length; j++) {
        console.log("State", states[j]);
        handle.on(states[j], logger);
    }
}

var initDb = function(callback) {
    for (var key in handles) {
        var handle = handles[key];
        handle.on('initDb', function(data) {
            callback(data);
        });
    };

    for (var key in handles) {
        var handle = handles[key];
        handle.emit('fetchDb', {});
    }
};

initDb(function(data) {
    console.log("End", data);
});
```

I can see each call returning data and *know* I have to wrap the first for loop, but I can't seem to wrap my head around what that would look like. Is there a way to wrap this logic with promises? The decoupled nature of the emit and callback are tripping me up.

Comment: `know I have to wrap the first for loop` ... for what purpose would you *wrap* the first loop? Can you describe the problem better. What do you mean by `group the results` for example

Comment: What I'd like to have done is have each of the N socket connections all use the same callback handler for a given emit and return all the results only when all subscriptions have returned. In the above, I have 2 connections and a single emit to "fetchDB" which sends data back to "initDb". I'd like to have the result of the "initDb" outer function return both results contained inside of the callback whereas right now, it sends them back as they come in.